# Why the small hole on coffee packaging? Why not?

Tags: packaging

I've seen alot of coffee bean packaging which have a hole on the front of them:

e.g.

[image]

While others do not:

e.g

[image]

(*Note that there is no hole present on the above packaging*)

## My Question:

What is the advantage of having a hole on one's coffee packaging v.s. not having one?

Comment: This question is a duplicate, please try searching for an answer before making a new post. Here are three posts in which this question was answered [1](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3081/what-is-a-flavorlock-bag/3082), [2](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/113), [3](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/4014).

Answer (score 0):

The existence of the de-gassing vent was answered here:

[What is the clear plastic sticker on New England Coffee bags for?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/4014/what-is-the-clear-plastic-sticker-on-new-england-coffee-bags-for)

If the manufacturer does not feel that the coffee (usually whole beans) will need C02 venting, there will be ho holes or vents. That will be the case if the coffee is packaged a week or so after roasting.

more:  https://www.coffeecrossroads.com/coffee-101/how-to-store-coffee-to-keep-it-fresh

some boutique coffee packages have an aroma vent - for you to squeeze the bag and smell the coffee.